# Change python2 library pybloomfilter to python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to use pybloomfilter package: https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap, 
I managed to install it under python3, but it seems the saved file does not have the original information (under python2, this won't happen), I looked into source code and it seems there is nothing specific to python2, so I am totally lost on how to make this library compatible with python3.

EDIT1: 
by "not have the original information", I mean, when I add some string into the filter, then I end the program, the next time, I use open to load the filter, the filter is clear, it does not remember the added strings.

Comment: the setup.py is missing the brackets to a print statement, how on earth did you install it for python 3?

Comment: this is where I changed

Comment: after changing this, you should be able to install, I am not asking how to install it, after install it, the normal use is fine, as long as you passed binary string, but saved file cannot be used.

Comment: I was testing it with python 2.7 and wasn't able to correctly use save files so I'm really not sure how to help here. sorry.

Comment: basically, you use the bloom filter with a file mmapped to memory, then you finish your program, the next time, you can use open to load the file and use it, it will contain all the information you added last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pybloomfiltermmap3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybloomfiltermmap3/0.4.15) is a Python 3 fork of pybloomfiltermmap by Michael Axiak (@axiak).

```
class pybloomfilter.BloomFilter(capacity : int, error_rate : float[,
                                filename=None : string ][, perm=0755 ])
```

Install:

Please have Cython installed. Please note that this version is for Python 3. In case you are using Python 2, please see
https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap.

To install:

```
$ pip install cython 
$ pip install pybloomfiltermmap3
```

to build and install the module.

And there is a instance method to sync the file:

```
BloomFilter.sync()
  Forces a sync() call on the underlying mmap file object.
  Use this if you are about to copy the file and you want to be Sure (TM)
  you got everything correctly.
```